# What's the semantics of return from block inside ensured blocks?

Tags: smalltalk

Assume we have the following sequence of methods:

```
m1
    self m2: [^1]

m2: block
    self m3: block.
    Processor := nil "crash!"

m3: block
    [block value] ensure: [^2]
```

The question is what's the value of `anObject m1`?

In other words, is the semantics of `[ˆ2]` well defined as an ensured block? There are two possibilities:

1. **The return from block is ignored in ensured blocks**: In this case `m1` will return with `1`.
2. **The return from block is honored in ensured blocks**: In this case the image will crash.

Please note that I'm not asking what will happen. I'm rather interested in the definition of the execution flow.

---

**EDIT**

COROLLARY 1 (as confirmed by Lukas in his answer below): Not a good programming style!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check page 23 of the [Draft of ANSI Smalltalk Standard](http://smalltalk.org/versions/ANSISmalltalk/ANSISmalltalkStandard_v1.9_199712_NCITS_X3J20_draft.pdf) that describes the return statement and its interaction with `ensure:` blocks:

> If the evaluation of a termination block concludes with the execution of a return statement the result is undefined.